# (SHELLSCRIPT) Script con 1 parámetro mín y 3 parámetros máx, y debe visualizar el número de el primer número hasta ese determinado parámetro

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Quiero realizar un **Shellscript** con 1 parámetro mínimo y 3 parámetros de máximo, y debe visualizar el número de el primer número hasta ese determinado parámetro.

Para que me entendáis mejor, me gustaría hacer esto:

```
./prueba.sh 2 5
```

Salida por pantalla:

```
Valor 2: 1, 2   
Valor 5: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

La siguiente foto contiene el código que llevo hasta ahora, espero que me podáis echar una mano, ya que no sé como continuar.Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y para qué es el último parámetro? ¿Qué debería devolver si dijeras `./prueba.sh 2 5 7`?

Comment: Devolvería la cadena de carácteres de 2, 5 y 7:

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre hacer el script de dos maneras muy resumidas, la primera, y creo que más entendible, es con un bucle `for` sencillo.

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $# < 1 || $# > 3 ]] \
    && echo Se necesitan entre 1 a 3 parametros \
    && exit 1

for parametro in $@
do
    echo Valor: $(seq -s ' ' 1 $parametro)
done
```

Lo que no me gusta es el ciclo `for`, en caso de que a ti no te guste, está otra opción con `xargs`.

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $# < 1 || $# > 3 ]] \
    && echo Se necesitan entre 1 y 3 parametros \
    && exit 1

xargs -d " " -I {} bash -c 'echo Valor: $(seq -s " " 1 {})' <<< "$@"
```

En ambos casos me sirvo de dos variables internas de `bash`: una es `$#`, que muestra la cantidad de parámetros ingresados; la otra es `$@` que es un array que contiene los parámetros ingresados.

En el primer ejemplo lo uso para alimentar al comando `for`, en el segundo ejemplo lo uso para alimentar a `xargs`.

En el segundo ejemplo uso el comando `seq`, que imprime una secuencia de números, con la indicación (con el parámetro `-s " "`) de que separe la salida con espacios.

El resultado de este código te dará lo siguiente en ambos casos.

```
$ ./parametros.sh
Se necesitan entre 1 y 3 parametros
$ ./parametros.sh 2 3 4 5
Se necesitan entre 1 y 3 parametros
$ ./parametros.sh 2 3 4
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
```

No requieres ninguna función (y a veces ni el uso de bucles) cuando ya hay programas que se encargan de ejecutar según cierta cantidad de líneas, caracteres, o repetir según la entrada. Por ejemplo, `xargs` construye y ejecuta lineas de comando según lo que se le ingrese, en este caso lo que le ingresamos son los parámetros con los que se corrió el programa.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @ihenryy93 De nada, si te sirvió mi respuesta, no olvides puntuarla positivamente si te funcionó, para que otros que tengan preguntas semejantes puedan notar fácilmente si es útil si se acomoda a su caso.

Comment: Nótese que `seq` tiene como primer parámetro el 1 por defecto. Creo a todo esto que la solución es un poco compleja para un principiante y un `seq` de toda la vida con un pipe a `tr` o `sed` se entendería mucho mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que algo así es lo que necesitas:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" ]
then
        echo -n "Valor 1: "
        for ((I=1;I<=$1;I++))
        do
                echo -n " " $I
        done
        echo ""
fi

if [ "$2" ]
then
        echo -n "Valor 2: "
        for ((I=1;I<=$2;I++))
        do
                echo -n " " $I
        done
        echo ""
fi

if [ "$3" ]
then
        echo -n "Valor 3: "
        for ((I=1;I<=$3;I++))
        do
                echo -n " " $I
        done
        echo ""
fi
```

La salida sería tal que así:

```
Valor 1:   1  2  3
Valor 2:   1  2  3  4  5
Valor 3:   1  2  3  4  5  6
```

Por cierto que este código está pidiendo una función a gritos XD así que ahí va, y mejorando un poco la salida con comas ;-)

```
#!/bin/bash

procesar()
{
        if [ $# -eq 2 ]
        then
                echo -n "Valor "
                echo -n $1
                echo -n " : "
                for ((I=1; I<= $2; I++))
                do
                        let NUM=$2
                        echo -n " " $I 
                        if [ $NUM -eq $I ]
                        then
                                echo  ""
                        else
                                echo -n ","
                        fi
                done
        fi
}


procesar 1 $1 
procesar 2 $2 
procesar 3 $3
```

La salida quedaría así:

```
➜  /tmp ./prueba.sh 5 6 5
Valor 1 :   1,  2,  3,  4,  5
Valor 2 :   1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6
Valor 3 :   1,  2,  3,  4,  5
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora lo probaré, y sí, también he pensado en las funciones, pero no las he usado nunca, por eso lo intentaba con estructuras más o menos simples para lo que sé xd

Comment: Ya modifiqué con una funcion ;-) @ihenryy93