# Visualizar los números entre 1 y el valor insertado como primer parámetro

Tags: bash, shell-script

Lo que he puesto en el título. Es como algo introductorio, ésto lo tengo, el problema lo tengo en que quiero que al ejecutar el script si no está comprendido el parámetro entre 1 y 100 o no se le pasa el parámetro, muestre un mensaje de error y la forma de hacerlo correctamente.

Os paso el código que tengo hasta ahora.

Espero que me podáis echar una mano, gracias.

```
#!/bin/bash
MAYOR=100
CONTADOR=1
echo "Introduce un valor"
if [ $1 -gt $MAYOR ]
then
  echo "Error, insertar número del 1 a 100"
fi

echo "Introduzca de nuevo su valor"
while [ $CONTADOR -lt $1 ]
do
  echo "Número $CONTADOR"
  let CONTADOR=CONTADOR+1
done
if [ $1 -le $MAYOR ]
then
  echo "Número $CONTADOR" 
fi
```

La salida que da mi código:

```
./script.sh 4
Numero 1
Numero 2
Numero 3 
Numero 4
```

El problema es que cuando pongo más de 100 no me coge el mensaje de error y me sigue sacando la cuenta del número 1 hasta un número mayor que 100 (parámetro insertado al inicio del script).

Comment: no añadas la resolución como parte de la respuesta. En su lugar, añade una respuesta explicándolo

Comment: Esta es la genérica: [(SHELLSCRIPT) Script con 1 parámetro mín y 3 parámetros máx, y debe visualizar el número de el primer número hasta ese determinado parámetro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/314153/shellscript-script-con-1-par%c3%a1metro-m%c3%adn-y-3-par%c3%a1metros-m%c3%a1x-y-debe-visualizar-e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si he entendido bien tu pregunta debería ser algo así:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAYOR=100
CONTADOR=1

if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
        VALOR=$1
else
        VALOR=0
fi

until [ $VALOR -gt 1  -a  $VALOR -lt 100 ];
do
        echo "Error, el parámtero debería ser un valor entre 1 y 100, pruebe de nuevo"
        read VALOR
done

while [ $CONTADOR -lt $VALOR ]
do
          echo "Número $CONTADOR"
            let CONTADOR=CONTADOR+1
done
```

Si no se introdujo el valor adecuado como parámetro lo preguntamos, para eso usamos `read` y lo preguntamos dentro de un bucle `until` hasta que el valor cumpla con los requisitos.

> ```
> until [ $VALOR -gt 1  -a  $VALOR -lt 100 ];
> do
>         echo "Introduce un valor"
>         read VALOR
> done
> ```

Una vez se cumplan pasamos al siguiente paso, que por lo que veo es ir decrementándolo.

Espero te sirva ;-)

Comment: No es eso exactamente, primero porque los quiero como parámetros, es decir, el script seguido de un parámetro, si cumple que va de 1 a 100, sale repetido del 1 hasta el valor introducido, si el número es mayor que 100 o no sé inserta un parámetro debe de salir un mensaje de error.

Comment: No cambia mucho  el código @ihenryy93, ahora ya está adaptado.  Lo importante es que no te salía por que no preguntabas dentro de un bucle ;-)

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente mantén un bucle infinito del que salgas cuando se produzca la inserción del valor válido.

Luego, usa `seq` para generar el listado de números, no hace falta crearlo a mano :)

```
#!/bin/bash

min=1
max=100

while true
do
    read -p "introduce valor " valor
    (( "$min" <= "$valor" && "$valor" <= "$max" )) && break
done

seq "$min" "$valor"
```