# ¿Cómo leo múltiples valores y luego calculo mínimo, máximo y media de estos?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Quiero sacar el promedio de una variable que pido por teclado y que guarda 20 valores. Necesito sacar el promedio total entre todos, es decir, como si sumase 20 veces el mismo campo y luego lo dividiera por 20.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto, ya sea con bucles o algo?

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash
VALOR=0
MAYOR=0
MENOR=999
CONTADOR=1

while [ $CONTADOR -le 20 ]
      do
            echo “Introduce un valor”
            read VALOR
                  if [ $VALOR -gt $MAYOR ]
                        then
                              MAYOR=$VALOR
                  fi
                        if [ $VALOR -le $MENOR ]
                              then
                                    MENOR=$VALOR
                       fi
                            MEDIA=`expr  \( $VALOR + $VALOR + VALOR + VALOR +  VALOR + $VALOR + $VALOR + VALOR + VALOR + VALOR + $VALOR + $VALOR + VALOR + VALOR + VALOR + $VALOR + $VALOR + VALOR + VALOR + VALOR \)  \/ 20
                             CONTADOR=$(($CONTADOR+1)
      done
echo “El mayor es $MAYOR”
echo “El menor es $MENOR”
echo “La media es $MEDIA”
```

Se puede ver que tengo un contador para los 20 números para sacar también el mayor y menor número que le pase, pues la media la tengo de la forma que podéis ver, colocando la expresión con la variable 20 veces y dividida por 20.

Por eso quiero una forma mucho más corta de escribirlo, ya que no sé si existe alguna forma de por ejemplo sumar la variable 20 veces sin escribirlo y hacer el promedio.

**SOLUCIÓN SENCILLA:**
Se tienen que añadir las siguiente variables y ya sumaríamos el total más todos los 20 datos de la variable valor y en la media la dividimos entre el contador que era 20.

TOTAL=0
MEDIA=0

VALOR=VALOR+TOTAL

MEDIA=VALOR /CONTADOR

VISUALIZA “La media es MEDIA”

Comment: Centremos el tema: ¿tiene que ser en Bash? ¿El usuario debe introducir los 20 valores (¿siempre 20?), a mano o puede leerlo de un fichero? Siempre va bien tener ejemplos de entrada y salida deseada

Comment: Si es en Bash, el usuario siempre introduce 20 valores y a mano.

Comment: No se cambia el título para indicar que algo está resuelto. Marca como aceptada la respuesta que solucionó tu problema (o añade tu respuesta y márcala)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes leer los datos en un array, más limpio y fácil de tratar después:

```
#!/bin/bash

min=1
max=100
num_valores=20
valores=()

for ((i=0; i<$num_valores; i++)); do
    echo "$i"
    while true
    do
        read -p "introduce valor " valor
        (( "$min" <= "$valor" && "$valor" <= "$max" )) && valores+=("$valor") && break
    done
done

echo "${valores[@]}"
```

Nótese que uso código tomado de [mi respuesta en una pregunta similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/314819/83) en la parte de leer contenido.

Para conseguir el mínimo, máximo y media de valores, lo mejor es usar Awk:

```
awk '{sum+=$1;
      vals++;
      min = ($1 < min) || !min ? $1 : min;
      max = ($1 > max) || !max ? $1 : max
     }
     END {print min, max, sum/vals}'
```

Por ejemplo:

```
$ awk '{sum+=$1; vals++; min = ($1 < min) || !min ? $1 : min; max = ($1 > max) || !max ? $1 : max} END {print min, max, sum/vals}' <<< '1
2
3
18
9
5'
1 18 6.33333
```

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurren dos maneras.

La primera es con el uso de `datamash` que es un comando en línea que hace operaciones estadísticas, aritméticas y textuales sencillas. Si no lo tienes instalado, puedes hacerlo con `sudo apt install datamash -y`.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i valores_deseados=3
declare -a valores

for (( i = 0; i < valores_deseados; i++ ))
do
    read -p "Ingresa un valor: " numero
    valores+=("$numero")  # Añadimos los números a un array.
done

tr ' ' '\n' <<< "${valores[*]}" | datamash --header-out max 1 min 1 mean 1 | column -t
# Donde uso column para imprimir en columnas.
```

Resultando.

```
$ ./maxmin2.sh
Ingresa un valor: 6
Ingresa un valor: 6
Ingresa un valor: 12
max(field-1)  min(field-1)  mean(field-1)
12            6             8
```

La segunda es con un script de bash que hace todo con bash salvo calcular el promedio, eso lo hace con `bc` (con sus limitaciones) y `awk`, además de guardar y desempaquetar en un formato tipo json.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i valores_deseados=3
declare -a sumar      # Mientras capturamos lo que ingresa el usuario
                      #+ aprovechamos el tiempo para sumar lo que ha ingresado.
declare -A resultado  #  Un array que contiene la estructura
                      #+ información para desempaquetar al final.
resultado=(
    [min]=""
    [max]=""
    [promedio]=""
)

for (( i = 0; i < valores_deseados; i++ )); do
    read -p "Ingresa un valor: " numero

    if [[ "${resultado[max]}" ]]; then #  Esto es sólo para incializar el
                                       #+ contenido del array.
        [[ "$numero" > "${resultado[max]}" ]] && resultado[max]="$numero"
        #           ^^-------------- Si el numero es mayor que el que
        #                            ya se encuentra, entonces lo ponemos 
        #                            como máximo.
        [[ "$numero" < "${resultado[min]}" ]] && resultado[min]="$numero"
        #           ^^-------------- Si el numero es menor que el que
        #                            ya se encuentra, entonces lo ponemos 
        #                            como mínimo.
    else # Aquí sólo es para inicializar
        resultado[max]="$numero"
        resultado[min]="$numero"
    fi
    suma+=("$numero")  # Añadimos los números a un array.
done

#echo "scale=2; $(IFS='+'; echo "${suma[*]}")/${valores_deseados}"

#  Usamos el programa bc para calcular el promedio con puntos decimales pero con problemas con los
#+ problemas con los negativos.
#resultado[promedio]="$( 
#    bc -l <<< "scale=2; $(IFS='+'; echo "${suma[*]}")/${valores_deseados}" 
#)"

# O usamos awk sin problemas con los negativos
resultado[promedio]="$( 
    awk -v RS=" " '{sum+=$1; cant++}END{print "promedio:" sum/cant}' <<< "${suma[@]}"
)"

#awk -v RS=" " '{sum+=$1; cant++}END{print "promedio:" sum/cant}' <<< "${suma[@]}"

# Desempaquetamos de una forma agradable.
for valor in ${!resultado[@]}; do
    echo "$valor: ${resultado[$valor]}"
done
```

Resultando en algo por el estilo.

```
$ ./maxmin.sh
Ingresa un valor: 4.2
Ingresa un valor: 32
Ingresa un valor: -32
promedio: promedio:1.4
min: 32
max: 4.2
```